# Detail band of subreport not showing

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

My main report contains 5 fields, 4 of them are of type ***java.lang.String*** and the last one is of type ***java.util.List***. I used its latter as the data source for the *subreport*. I set the *datasource* of the *subreport*.

*Subreport* properties:

*Connection Type*       : ***Use a datasource expression***
*Datasource Expression* : ***new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{Field5})***

Passing of data is working fine (I guess) because when I fill the report inside the *Java* application. I can view the data passed to fields 1 to 4 but in field 5, at first, I can't verify because the *subreport* does not show data, only the static texts defined in the *Column Header*.

Then when I placed the fields of the *subreport* in the *Page Footer*, I found out that the data is passed successfully, the problem is that the *Detail* band itself is not showing.

Why is it not showing?

In the *subreport* properties, I have:

*When no data*: ***All Sections, No Detail***

Please can anyone shed some light on this.

Comment: I am having the same problem with one newly-created report. The *Detail* band does not display anything, not even a static field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem for more than 1 day. In the application I am developing on there are multiple *JasperReports* which work. I encountered this problem when adding a new one. No matter what I tried, nothing displayed in the *Detail* band. I tried everything from triple-checking the Controller that populates the report, to upgrading to the latest `jasperreports` jar and latest `iReports` version. Nothing seemed to work.

The problem is that the report is set by default to: `When No Data: All Sections, No Detail`, which basically means that if no data is sent to the report, it will display all sections, except for the *Detail* one.

Although besides static text which I was using to test the report I was passing parameters directly from the Java Controller, it did not work until I added an `EXEC [myFunction] $P{parameterId}` to the *Query Text* property of the report. The function is a simple straightforward one, which takes a `parameterId` passed from Java as a parameter and returns something. (also, make sure you set the *The language for the dataset query    sql* property to *SQL*).

To sum up, for some reason the report doesn't seem to take the Java parameters as data (so it displays all the sections, except for *Detail*), so when I explicitly call a SQL function which returns some parameters and put them into my detail page, it works.

I hope this helps you, I busted my head for 10 hours to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sample.

The *POJO* (Bean):

```java
public class BeanWithList {

    private List<String> m_cities;
    private Integer m_id;

    public BeanWithList(List<String> cities, Integer id) {
        m_cities = cities;
        m_id = id;
    }

    public List<String> getCities() {
        return m_cities;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return m_id;
    }
}
```

The code to fill report:

```java
public static void testBuildPdf() {
    try {

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        params.put("BeanSubreport", JasperCompileManager.compileReport(subreportSource));

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(masterSource);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, getDataSource());

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static JRDataSource getDataSource() {
    Collection<BeanWithList> coll = new ArrayList<BeanWithList>();

    BeanWithList bean = new BeanWithList(Arrays.asList("London", "Paris"), 1);

    coll.add(bean);

    bean = new BeanWithList(Arrays.asList("London", "Madrid", "Moscow"), 2);
    coll.add(bean);

    bean = new BeanWithList(Arrays.asList("Rome"), 3);
    coll.add(bean);

    return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(coll);
}
```

The subreport *jrxml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport .. leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <field name="city" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{city}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The master *jrxml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <parameter name="BeanSubreport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="cities" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <title>
        <band height="103" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="138" y="28" width="258" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Bean with List sample]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[City name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{cities})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{BeanSubreport}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be:

[image: The report in PDF format]

---

The main trick of this sample is the using of *`_THIS`* "variable".

For more information you can read [JavaBean Data Sources](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources) article.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the subreport parameter during runtime.

For those who encounter the same problem I just stored the JasperReport object (datatype is `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport`) in a java variable then pass the variable to the parameter inside the report. This parameter is set as the value for **Subreport Expression**. Expression class of the subreport parameter should be `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass parameters to FillManager, don't use null, use JREmptyDataSource.

Correct way:
JasperFillManager.fillReport(this.getReportTemplate(JASPER_REPORT_EXPIRY_LETTER),this.parameters,new JREmptyDataSource());

Wrong way:
JasperFillManager.fillReport(this.getReportTemplate(JASPER_REPORT_EXPIRY_LETTER),this.parameters, null);

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

public class MyForm extends JFrame {



    public static JasperDesign jasperDesign;
    public static JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    public static JasperReport jasperReport;
    static JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrBeanCollectionDataSource;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyForm frame = new MyForm();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MyForm() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 431, 286);
        setTitle("ThaiCreate.Com Java GUI Tutorial");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);


        // Button Report
        JButton btnOpenReport = new JButton("Open Report");
        btnOpenReport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                Connection connect = null;

                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" ,"root","");
                    System.out.println("Connected....");
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) 
                {e1.printStackTrace();} 
                catch (SQLException e) 
                {e.printStackTrace();}

                // Application path
                FileInputStream report = null;
                try {
                     FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\report1.jrxml"));
                      try 
                     {

                        jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
                        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
                        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, connect);
                        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "E:\\demo.pdf");



//                      Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:/ReceiptReport.pdf"));

                    } catch (JRException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 



                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("ThaiCreate.Com Customer Report");
                frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800,600);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JRViewer(jasperPrint));
                frame.setVisible(true);

                try {
                    connect.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        btnOpenReport.setBounds(137, 98, 146, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnOpenReport);
        setResizable (false);
    }
}
```

Comment: please download frist library frile from below link >>>>>http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/latest/download

Comment: Than copy all file from lib frolder to your project .